# Assign value to property node

Tags: labview

I starting using LabVIEW about 1 week ago. In a tutorial I watched this picture [image: Property value]

I am wondering how can I assign the value "Disabled and Grayed out" to disabled property value of the button?

Comment: You should get familiar with references: https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/glang/property_node/

http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/property-node-example/td-p/157915

Comment: Create the Disabled property node from the control terminal, change it to write if necessary, then create a constant for it. All these are accessible through the right-click menu.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to create property nodes in LabVIEW. This method is the quickest and easiest and matches your picture.

1. Add the button to your front panel.
2. Right-Click and go to Create >> Property Node >> Disabled in the menus. Click on this.
3. LabVIEW will automatically switch to the block diagram and let you drop the property node.
4. By default it is a read node. Right-Click on the block where it says "Disabled" and select Change To Write in the menu (There is also Change All To Write if you have multiple properties.
5. Hover over the input so you get the wiring symbol. Right-Click and select Create Constant to create the correct Enum constant to write to it.

That is the basics and the way most people start out - a couple of extra tips:

- The node is expandable hover at the bottom and you get the resize block, drag this down and you can set more than one property on the same node. These are set in order from top to bottom.
- Left click on each property to change which property it is.
- Right-Click and go to Link To... in the menu to change which button it applies to.