# How does one pass the "dp" argument in SetCurrentValue() in Windows UIElement class in LabVIEW?

Tags: c#, .net, labview

I am trying to change the value of a Child property in an `ElementHost` class in LabVIEW. I thought that could be accomplished by invoking the `SetCurrentValue` method for it but I am confused as to what to pass for the `DependencyProperty` argument (the "dp"). I have looked over the definition of the function at MSDN and other questions on Stack Overflow but I have not found any straightforward answer (or I might have just missed it and would appreciate directions).

[image: snippet]

Comment: Can you add any code snippets to the question?

Comment: @benhorgen, just included a picture of the code. I am unsure how to include an actual code snippet since LabVIEW is a graphical coding language. Thank you for the help in the edit!

Comment: https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/Snippet

Comment: @AdrianKeister just added the Snippet but Stack Overflow won't allow me to directly display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found through [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893962/assign-value-to-property-node#:~:text=There%20are%20a%20couple%20of%20ways%20to%20create,diagram%20and%20let%20you%20drop%20the%20property%20node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893962/assign-value-to-property-node#:%7E:text=There%20are%20a%20couple%20of%20ways%20to%20create,diagram%20and%20let%20you%20drop%20the%20property%20node). One can set the Property Node in Write mode and "skip" having to call the UIElement.